# how to wait in the thread until it receives connect callback from google Api client

Tags: java, multithreading

I don't have much experience about multi threading so kindly help me out. I have a background thread in which i connect my google api client to find my current location. When i call **myGoogleApiClient.connect()** it tries to connect and i receive a call back when it's connected but after calling connect method my flows go back. I want my program to wait there and continue executing my next tasks. Here is the code

```
public class CurrentLocation implements GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener,GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks{
    private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
    private String placesTextFile;
    Context context;
    String TAG="NearbyPlaces";

    CurrentLocation(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
        mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient
                .Builder(context)
                .addApi(Places.GEO_DATA_API)
                .addApi(Places.PLACE_DETECTION_API)
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .build();
    }

    private void connect() {
        Log.d(TAG,"run called");
       if(mGoogleApiClient.isConnected())
            findLocations();
        else
            mGoogleApiClient.connect(); //Here my flow goes back but i want my program to wait here till it gets onConnected callback

    }
    private void findLocations(){
     // some code here that need to be executed when my client connects
    }
    @Override
    public void onConnected(@Nullable Bundle bundle) {
        Log.d(TAG,"Google Client is Connected");
        findLocations();
    }
}
```

I'm calling my connect method from a timer task like this

```
private void StartTracker() {
        Log.d(TAG,"TimerTask is in waiting state now");
        timerScheduler.schedule(new TimerTask() {
            @Override
            public void run() {

                while (isServiceRunning){
                    try {
                        currentLocation.connect();
//video recorder should only be started when i will find out my current location successfully
                        videoRecorder.startVideoRecorder();
                        Thread.sleep(getRandomRecordingDuration());
                        videoRecorder.stopVideoRecorder();
                        Thread.sleep(delayTime);

                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                }

            }
        }, delayTime);
    }
```

Comment: How does _your_ `connect()` method get invoked? You haven't shown us enough of your code.  The wait should be happening in the invoker of `connect()`, and it should wait on a semaphore that is signalled by the `onConnected()` method.

Comment: @JimGarrison, why not wait within `connect()`?

Comment: @JimGarrison i have edited my post.. kindly check it again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so finally found the answer of my question. I used this technique to resolve my issue.

```
//for waiting to complete another job
 synchronized (synchObj) {
            try { synchObj.wait();}
            catch (InterruptedException ie) {

            }
        }

//when job is done and want the execution from where it was stoped
 synchronized (synchObj) {
                            synchObj.notify();
                        }
```

followed this guy to solve my problem http://forums.devshed.com/java-help-9/block-thread-callback-method-called-thread-904920.html

Answer (score 1):

According to your code , you just want to do something everytime after you call the "connect" method and successfully connect.So maybe you'd better to do the things in the call back "onConnected".